# how update quantity in javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, cart

I have table like this.

```
<?php $no=1; 
  foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items): ?>
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $items['rowid']?>" class="rowid" id="<?php echo $items['rowid']?>" name="rowid"/>
 <tr><td> <?php echo $no; 
          $data = array('id' => $items['id'], 'name' => 'id', 'value' => $items['id']);
          echo form_hidden($data); ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $items['name']?><?php $items['options']['exp']?></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $items['qty']?>" name="qty" id="<?php echo $items['id']?>" class="qty"/>
         <button class="update" id="<?php echo 'up'.$items['id']?>" style="margin-top:-10px"><i class=" icon-refresh"></i>update</button></td>
     <td><?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['price']); ?></td>
  </tr>
```

It'll display like this :

```
No.  Name       Qty       Price   subtotal                                                            
 1.   xxx   |1| [update]  500       500
 2.   xox   |1| [update]  505       505
```

i want to qty xox. here's my code

```
$(".update").click(function(){
   var idbarang = $(".qty").attr('id');
   var qty = $(".qty").val();
   var row = (this.id);
   var rowid = row.substr(2);
```

but when i update it, xxx always changes. I think because of attr('id').
How can update xox?

Comment: In HTML id should be unique overall HTML elements

Comment: the html attribute ID must be unique to be valid html. You are also selecting all elements with the $(".qty") query. Debug your variables and you should be able to see that you got a array.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

To correct the html I used `data-id` custom attributes. To learn more about custom attributes, check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) and their description of how to use them.

```
<table>
    <tr><td>xxx</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty" data-id="123"/>
        <button class="update" id="123">update</button></td>
    <td class="display" data-id="123">500</td>
    <td>[subtotal]</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>xox</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty" data-id="121"/>
        <button class="update" id="121">update</button></td>
    <td class="display" data-id="121">505</td>
    <td>[subtotal]</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

### JavaScript

After that, I used [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) in jQuery to differentiate between the different rows, so that the each button changed the correct row.

```
$(".update").click(function(e){
   var t = e.target;
   var idbarang = $(t).attr('id');
   var qty = $("[data-id='"+idbarang+"'].qty").val();
   $("[data-id='"+idbarang+"'].display").html(qty);
})
```

As mentioned, id's must be unique (more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id)), but since you seem to be using them to identify a product id and not a traditional DOM element ID, I tried to keep the spirit.

You could also have structured things more semantically by using the `data-id` attribute in your row declaration (i.e. `<tr data-id='123'></tr>`) and then used child selectors, such as:

```
   $("tr[data-id='"+idbarang+"'] .display").html(qty);
```

with the space between the `]` and the `.`.

### Conclusion

You can see everything come together here in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tJEQ/2/). Hope that helps.

Comment: well, it didn't work on me. I've console.log(qty) and idbarang but the result were undefined

Comment: it's working in the linked fiddle. Not sure how to help beyond that.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".update").click(function(){
    var qty = $("#121").val();
```

However, id's are supposed to be unique throughout an HTML document. Currently your button and input have the same id, which is not valid HTML.